# Django - Template bitmask check

Tags: python, django, django-templates, bitmask, django-template-filters

Consider this list:

```py
options = [
    {
        'name': 'Option 1',
        'plan': 0b001,
    },
    {
        'name': 'Option 2',
        'plan': 0b010,
    },
    {
        'name': 'Option 3',
        'plan': 0b110,
    },
]
```

**Question**: How can I display this list as

```
         plan1 plan2 plan3
Option 1               ✔
Option 2         ✔      
Option 3   ✔     ✔
```

from a template like

```html
{% for option as options %}
<div>
  <div>{{ option.name }}</div>
  <div>{{ option.plan|bitmaskcheck:0b001 }}</div>
  <div>{{ option.plan|bitmaskcheck:0b010 }}</div>
  <div>{{ option.plan|bitmaskcheck:0b100 }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

with a kind of `bitmaskcheck` operator ? (Or would there be simpler ?)

Comment: As Python is very high-level programming language, I would not try to create bitmasks as it adds more complexity to the problem without any performance benefits. Instead options.plan object could be a dictoinary where you have options.plan["plan1"] = True or False. Then you could simple check it liek {{ option.plan.plan1 }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [suggested by @MikkoOhtamaa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254432/django-template-bitmask-check#comment-32020909), I'll use a dictionnary

```py
options = [
    {
        'name': 'Option 1',
        'plan': {1: True,},
    },
    {
        'name': 'Option 2',
        'plan': {2: True,},
    },
    {
        'name': 'Option 3',
        'plan': {2: True, 3: True,},
    },
]
```

Then I should be able to make my checks as:

```html
{% for option as options %}
<div>
  <div>{{ option.name }}</div>
  <div>{% if option.plan.1 %}✔{% endif %}</div>
  <div>{% if option.plan.2 %}✔{% endif %}</div>
  <div>{% if option.plan.3 %}✔{% endif %}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```